# atof randomly not working correclty

Tags: c++, atof, g++4.8

I seem to be having some weird problem with **atof()** function not converting some values correctly. For the same values **atoi()** works perfectly.
Here's a little snippet of what I'm doing:

```
...
// frequencies is a std::string in format a10d50f20 etc. i.e. letter|frequency in %  
// 6 - 48 characters, always correctly formatted 
for (size_t i = 0; i < frequencies.size(); i+=3)
{
  // #1
  double percentage = atof(frequencies.substr(i+1, i+2).c_str()) / 100;
  // #2
  double percentage = static_cast<double>(atoi(frequencies.substr(i+1, i+2).c_str())) / 100;

  cout << frequencies[i] << " - " << percentage << endl;
}
...
```

For some strange reason only method #2 seems to be always working correctly.

### Sample Outputs

#### FOR: frequencies = "a30b30c40"

**Both** methods work correctly, giving me:
a - 0.30
b - 0.30
c - 0.40

#### FOR: frequencies = "a10b10c10d10e10f50"

with **atof()** I get:
a - 0.10
b - 0.10
c - 1000000000.00 **!?**
d - 1000000000.00 **!?**
e - 0.10
f - 0.50
while **atoi() correctly** gives me this:
a - 0.10
b - 0.10
c - 0.10
d - 0.10
e - 0.10
f - 0.50

p.s. I can't use std::stod because mingw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of `substr` is a length, not an offset.

When you call `substr(i+1, i+2)` for `d` you're getting the whole remainder of the string, which is then parsed as exponential notation `10e10` i.e. 10 * 10<sup>10</sup>.

Comment: +1. Aside: In the fortran world, the `d` in `10d10` means double precision number in floating point representation. Some versions of `atof` "know" this, and that's apparently why `10d10` also was interpreted as 10*10^10.

Answer (score 2):

For `d` the `atof` function took `10e10` as 10 x (10 ^ 10) = 1000000000.0 (in engineering notation / standard form).

Did you really get 1000000000.0 for `c`? I dunno if the same thing happened as well.